# zf3 Listen to event triggered in another classes

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm stuck with this for a while.
I have a service for each entity when i trigger various events

Eg in ArticleService **saveArticle** method

```
$this->triggerEvent('articleSaved', ['saved' => $entity]);
```

Then i create an individual listener like below

```
class ArticleSavedListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    // ...
    
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 100)
    {
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(
            Events::ARTICLE_SAVED,
            [$this, 'onSaved'],
            $priority
        );
    }

    public function onSaved($event)
    {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

And the registration in Module.php

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap()
    {
        $application = $e->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        
        $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
        $articleService = $serviceManager->get(ArticleService::class);

        $articleSavedListener = $serviceManager->get(ArticleSavedListener::class);
        $articleSavedListener->attach($articleService->getEventManager());
    }
}
```

The point is i need to create a generic class **(listener)** listening all list of specific events with a very low priority. But for what i read since i declared them private i can't listen to them outside the registered class scope.

Help needed please.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by injecting default EventManager in all my mapper service factories `$container->get('EventManager')`... Maybe not what i expected but no other choice

Eg **HelpCenter\Service\AbstractServiceFactory.php**

```
class AbstractServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param array|null $options
     * @return mixed|object
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $objectManager = $container->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
        $moduleOptions = $container->get(ModuleOptions::class);
        $logger = $container->get('app_logger');
        $eventManager = $container->get('EventManager');

       /* @var $service AbstractServiceInterface */
       $service = new $requestedName($objectManager, $moduleOptions);
       $service->setLogger($logger);
       $service->setEventManager($eventManager);
       return $service;
    }
}
```